# TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Borré la carpeta del proyecto y lo volví a clonar y ahora me aparece este error. Antes no sucedía. Los demás compañeros tienen la misma configuración y no presentan el problema, sólo yo. 
¿Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema o algo similar con TS en el backend?
El comando que usamos para activar el servidor local es **npm run dev (nodemon)**.

El error es:

```
/home/toreohm/Documentos/proyectos/amez/amez-cfo-backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
       ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/utils/middleware/JwtValidation.ts:10:16 - error TS7006: Parameter '_err' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Mi tsconfig.json es el siguiente:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "es2016"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@controllers/*": ["controllers/*"],
      "@routers/*": ["routers/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["interfaces/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["constants/*"],
      "@service/*": ["service/*"],
      "@entities/*": ["entities/*"],
      "@classAbstract/*": ["classAbstract/*"],
      "@modulesMongo/*": ["modulesMongo/*"],
      "@schemaJoi/*": ["schemaJoi/*"]
    },
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "types/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "sonar-project.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"],
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"],
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Ya actualizaste TS?

Comment: Sí, desafortunadamente no soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, pero desconozco la causa del problema.

- Lo que hice fue borrar nuevamente la carpeta del proyecto y volver a clonarlo desde bitbucket.
- sudo rm -R carpeta
- git clone https://....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]